# Add new timestamp column with interval in dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark and I have a Spark dataframe. I want to add a new column timestamp interval with 15 minutes. Can anyone help please.

```
My Dataset:
+-------------+-----+-------
|id           |model|price  | 
+-------------+-----+-------
|2187233    |1      |54.13  |
|2187233    |1      |44.94  |
|2187233    |1      |39.84  |
|2187233    |1      |36.95  |
|99999653468|1      |108.06 |
|99999653468|1      |108.96 |
|99999653468|1      |108.84 |
|99999653468|1      |108.86 |
+-------------+-----+--------
```

Suppose current time is 2023-07-30 00:00:00

then Result should be:

```
+-------------+-----+------------------+-------------------+
|id           |model|price         |ds                 |
+-------------+-----+------------------+-------------------+
|2187233    |1      |54.13         |2023-07-30 00:00:00|
|2187233    |1      |44.94         |2023-07-30 00:15:00|
|2187233    |1      |39.84         |2023-07-30 00:30:00|
|2187233    |1      |36.95         |2023-07-30 00:45:00|
|99999653468|1      |108.06        |2023-07-30 00:00:00|
|99999653468|1      |108.96        |2023-07-30 00:15:00|
|99999653468|1      |108.84        |2023-07-30 00:30:00|
|99999653468|1      |108.86        |2023-07-30 00:45:00|
+-------------+-----+------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can achieve this using the `withColumn` function along with the `expr` function in `PySpark`. U need to import the necessary functions and create a `new column` with the desired `timestamp` intervals

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, current_timestamp
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("TimestampInterval").getOrCreate()
interval_minutes = 15

# Your DataFrame
data = [
    (2187233, 1, 54.13),
    (2187233, 1, 44.94),
    (2187233, 1, 39.84),
    (2187233, 1, 36.95),
    (99999653468, 1, 108.06),
    (99999653468, 1, 108.96),
    (99999653468, 1, 108.84),
    (99999653468, 1, 108.86)
]

columns = ["id", "model", "price"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("model")
df = df.withColumn("interval_num", (expr("row_number() OVER PARTITION BY id ORDER BY model") - 1))
df = df.withColumn("interval", expr(f"INTERVAL {interval_minutes} MINUTES * interval_num"))
df = df.withColumn("ds", current_timestamp() + col("interval"))

df = df.drop("interval_num", "interval")
df.show(truncate=False)
```